# Dynamically creating radio buttons using loop in react native

Tags: react-native

I am creating a sample application in react native. In this app, I have fetched API data in an array. What i need to do is that to create number of radio buttons according to number of elements in array. So i used **for loop** which executes from index position 0 to array length , but the problem is instead of displaying radio buttons equal to number of elements in array, it is just showing radio button for last element for that particular array.

**Below is the code**

```
    var json_response_SelectSegment = await AuthService.GetSegmentDropdown(this.state.machineId,this.state.orderBySegment,this.state.orderByDescendingSegment,this.state.allRecordsSegment);
    console.log("***got Segment Data*******",json_response_SelectSegment.data.data.segmentMainResponse.segmentResponse)
  var Json_respo_Segment=json_response_SelectSegment.data.data.segmentMainResponse.segmentResponse
  console.log("data = ",Json_respo_Segment.length)
  for(i=0;i<Json_respo_Segment.length;i++){
   console.log("**",Json_respo_Segment[i].Segment)
   console.log("**",Json_respo_Segment[i].SegmentId)
   this.state.radio_props_Segment=[{ label: Json_respo_Segment[i].Segment, value: Json_respo_Segment[i].Segment }]
   console.log("Hello : ",this.state.radio_props_Segment)
   
  }
```

**It is showing all the array elements in console.log(for example array contains 4 elements) but it is creating radio button for only last element in UI**

**Any solution please ?**

Comment: When using array to populate list of data, you can use your_array.push(itemData). In your code above you are only making assignment to array based on index, which is not adding list item to array, instead you make array with one last object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 const radioData = [];

  for(i = 0 ; i < Json_respo_Segment.length ; i++){
   
    radioData.push(
        { label: Json_respo_Segment[i].Segment, 
          value: Json_respo_Segment[i].Segment 
        }
     );   
  }

  const data = [...this.state.radio_props_Segment];
  data.push(radioData);
   
  this.setState({radio_props_Segment: data});
```